# Jekyll: Is there anyway to output all posts and collection types in a single for loop ordered by date?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have two collections defined for tutorials and articles within my Jekyll blog. I need to be able to display all the different collection types alongside posts and have them ordered by date. Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with some liquid code. By looping first over all collections one can capture the collection labels and use these to access all documents in all collections in a second for-loop.

```
{% for collection in site.collections %}
  {% capture label %}{{ collection | first }}{% endcapture %}
  <h3>All documents listed in collection '{{ label}}'</h3>

  {% for doc in site.collections.[label].docs %}
    <li>
      <span>{{ doc.date | date_to_string }}</span>
      <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ doc.url }}">{{ doc.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

This lists dates and titles of all documents per collection in chronological order. However, if one want **all** documents sorted in **one** list things get nasty. I hope, something similar to the code above is what you are looking for.